# count motifs in dna sequence

Tags: scoring, dna-sequence

I have these sequences:

```
GCAGGCATAGTCGGAACTGCTCTAAGCCTATTAATTCGAGCTGAGCTAAGCCAGCCTGGGGCTCTGCTCGGAGATGA
AGTGGGCTTGTTGGGACTGGTCTTTCTTTATTAATTCGTTTTGAGTTAGGCACTGTTGGAGTTTTATTAG---ATAA
GCAGGAATAGTTGGAACCGCCCTTAGCTTATTAATTCGAGCAGAACTCAGCCAACCTGGTGCCTTATTAGGGGATGA
GCTGGCATAGTAGGAACTGCCCTTAGCCTTTTAATTCGAGCAGAGCTCAGTCAACCCGGAGCCCTGCTCGGAGATGA
GCAGGAATAGTTGGAACTGCACTAAGCCTTTTAATTCGAGCTGAACTAAGCCAACCCGGAGCATTACTTGGAGACGA
```

They would be actually longer, but right not it is not important.

I would like to estimate a given value for the sequences given the number of motif/s in.

I would like to count a (number of) motif/s like `"ATCGCGCGCGCTTTAAA"` in a given sequence, and then use that number to estimate a value for that sequence.

I know that you can use a logical question to ask whether a given sequence has a motif but I would like to count them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EMBOSS Fuzznuc: http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/release/6.6/emboss/apps/fuzznuc.html

> fuzznuc searches for a specified PROSITE-style pattern in nucleotide sequences. Such patterns are specifications of a (typically short) length of sequence to be found. They can specify a search for an exact sequence or they can allow various ambiguities, matches to variable lengths of sequence and repeated subsections of the sequence. One or more nucleotide sequences are read from file. The output is a standard EMBOSS report file that includes data such as location and score of any matches.

For bioinformatics questions, you should ask biostars.org